# Integral $\left(\frac{x+y}{x-y}\right)^4$ using long division?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Alright, this one seems silly but I got a nasty answer when trying to break it up using long division.

How do you integrate  $\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\left(\dfrac{x+y}{x-y}\right)^4dydx$?

I don't need the whole thing worked out, I just can't seem to clean up the integrand for the first integral with respect to y.

Comment: what is the integrationsvariable?

Comment: You realize the denominator is zero when $x=y$?  I would try to make a change of variable, perhaps $u = x+y$ and $v = x-y$.

Comment: Apologies, I don't follow. Wouldn't u and -u be more helpful? Are you saying to take the partial integral with respect to u in that case?

Comment: Or did you mean integration by parts? Because in that case, I thought I needed u and dv?